# The parent model is not updated when hasMany relations are loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
1) var user = this.store.find('user', '1'); -> Works.

2) user.get('friends.content').length; -> Returns 0.

3) var friend = this.store.find('friend', '2'); -> Works.

4) user.get('friends.content').length; -> Still returns 0, it should be 1.
```

The same thing when I load friends with `findQuery`, it does not update the parent model. I am using the latest build of ember, ember-data.

Comment: Can you post the definition of your models?

Comment: For simple relation, it does not work. 

`App.User = DS.Model.extend({ friends: DS.hasMany('friend') });`

`App.Friend = DS.Model.extend({ user: DS.belongsTo('user') });`

Comment: What does the json returned by the server look like for Users and Friends?

Comment: user = { id: 1 },
friend = { id: 2, user_id: 1}. This does not update the user model's friend(computed), is there a workaround to update the parent model with its children?